# How to stop the redirect after FOG uninstall?

Tags: 11.04, redirect, fog

I have [uninstalled](http://www.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php?title=Uninstall_FOG) FOG Server from my Ubuntu 11.04

However, when I try to access the machine IP: http://192.168.0.22/

it is redirected to: http://192.168.0.22/fog/index.php and I get a 404 error.

what do I need to check in order to stop this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing, you probably edited  `/var/www/index.html`, as explained in the installation instructions (http://www.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php?title=Ubuntu_10.04, "Make fog accessible at the root of the server (optional)."). Remove this part:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=fog/index.php">
```

Comment: apparently I did, but because I usually do not delete files. I renamed that file to be: fog.index.php. and it seems that my server just grabbed that php file as the first call.  Editing that back to  index.php and removing the meta fixed it.  thanks